# Is cycling the best option to strength the thighs muscle and make them look smaller?

Tags: muscle, strength, workout, bicycling, thigh

I am concern about my thighs size.

I an adult men weighing 56.4 Kg, 165 cm tall (5.4 feet), considered as a short man.

My last visit to a nutritionist, was a disaster. She told me that I should not lose more weight. And I should focus on gaining muscles by going to gym or buying some home equipment to do so.

In my first visit, the weight was 57.5 Kg and the mass of body fat (MBF) was 10.5 kg
And the control of MBF was `+0.0`. So she told me to stop walking for 45 minutes per day, or at least walking less than that and increase the muscles build.

I was concern of my thighs size, while standing the diamter is 54 cm. And when I sit down it will go very wide.

The segmental assessment gave:

1. 1.89Kg of MBF and 7.77Kg of SLM (Soft Lead Mass) for the left leg
2. 1.88Kg of MBF and 7.86 of SLM for the right leg.

The dietitian told me to do some cycling to strength up the thighs muscle so the look will change and it will firm up when sitting.

Reading from this [article](https://totalwomenscycling.com/fitness/will-cycling-make-your-thighs-bigger):

> So yes, cycling will change the shape of your legs, but unless you’re
>   doing a LOT of squats, and maintaining the same levels of fat (by
>   eating A LOT), you’re not likely to get “bigger”.

And it made me confused about doing cycling or not.

So is cycling going to make my thighs bigger or smaller ? And what other things to do other than cycling to strengthen the muscles and make them look smaller? Squats are not an option as I don't want to get a curved bottom.

Answer (score 2):

Well as the article says, you will get bigger if you're squatting and maintaining high levels of fats. If you are cycling but eating less and not weight lifting your legs are going to become firmer and slimmer